# Search multiple strings in eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse, search

I need to search throughout the work-space for all files containing "String1" or "String2".How to achieve this in eclipse search ?

Comment: try `String1|String2`

Comment: how to get & working ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`Search` -> `File...` In `Containing text` enter `String1|String2` and check `Regular expression`. As `scope` you have to select `Workspace`

Comment: i just got the answer from [here](http://www.eclipse.org/tptp/home/downloads/installguide/gla_42/ref/rregexp.html) and was typing the answer .Any way thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you "pin" a search and open a new search window, the results from both searches will be highlighted throughout.