# Eclipse: Searching for a string in selected packages?

Tags: java, eclipse

How do you search for a string in classes in multiple selected packages?

[Search multiple strings in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482688/search-multiple-strings-in-eclipse) seems to search for the entire workspace, I would like to just search in selected packages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you could do the same but set the scope to "selected resources" (don't forget to select the packages).

Comment: "How do you search" there's no imperative steps in your answer. Thanks

Comment: @FredoCorleone well, the OP already had a set of imperative steps and just wanted to add an additional restriction which is what this answer provides.

Answer (score 6):

`Search` -> `File Search` -> `Working Set` -> `New` -> `Java` -> And from the selected project(s) add the package(s) you want to search in.

Comment: That would require to create new working sets for each search wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, but you can easily navigate through the packages you want to select. In case you want to select multiple, different ones (Kim Jong Woo wants), it is probably easier than using a reg exp.

Comment: Well, you could also just select those packages and search in the selected resources, no need to put those into a regex :)

Comment: Up to the user really. Good thing is that there are several options now ;)