# Search multiple strings in eclipse with AND operation

Tags: eclipse

I need to search throughout the work-space for all files containing "file1.txt" **AND** "file2.txt" as a string. How to achieve this in eclipse search?

possiblly duplicate of [Search multiple strings in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482688/search-multiple-strings-in-eclipse) but not worked with file names and AND operation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as  I know, you can't, but as a workaround :

You could search for file name patterns `file?.txt` and then in the search view, click on the `down arrow icon` on the right, `display as list` and only doubleclick `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` matches

Answer (score 0):

You will do two individual searches, one for `file1.txt` and one for `file2.txt`, and you will intersect the two results.

**Step 1.** Export the search results

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15138046/11233118) , you can install the Eclipse Search CSV Export plugin. In the Marketplace, search for 'csv export' - it is the first result. Once installed, just perform a File Search as usual; in the Search Tab, in the bar, click on this icon ([screenshot](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-search-csv-export#group-screenshots)) named 'Export Search Results as CSV' to export the results as a csv file.

Obviously, you will perform a second search, and export those results, too.

**Step 2.** Convert the .csv file to .xlsx format

As shown [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/01/convert-csv-excel/),in the section 'How to import CSV to Excel' , open Excel, go to Data tab > 'From Text',  browse the .csv file; in the wizard, choose 'Delimited' (instead of 'Fixed width'), as Delimiters, choose 'Comma', preview the columns and click OK.

Now that you have converted the data into a more readable format, you can also Save as >  .xlsx

Two columns are important here, Path and Location. I prefer Location, as it is an absolute location, not project relative.

Sort this column, select all its content, paste the content to a .txt file, save the .txt file. Do the same for your second search.

**Step 3.** Create the intersection of the lists of the Locations

At the previous step, you have copied the Locations column into a separate file, for each individual search. Navigate to [Venn webtools](http://bioinformatics.psb.ugent.be/webtools/Venn/) , browse the .txt files and click Submit.The output will show the Intersection and the Differences between the two files. The Intersection represents the Locations of the files that contain BOTH your search strings - a functionality that should have been offered by the IDE. Please note that this tool allows up to 3 files to be uploaded.